# How to change SQL query to automatically select the last 12 months of data?

Tags: sql-server, date

I currently have a query that I use to pull the total amount of revenue by state, each month, for the past 12 months. I was wondering if there was a way I could edit this query so that it automatically selects the last 12 months and I do not need to change the dates in the query every time I use it.

Here is some example DDL/DML:

```
DECLARE @ExampleData TABLE (SortCode NVARCHAR(2), LoadDate DATE, Tnet INT);
INSERT INTO @ExampleData (SortCode, LoadDate, Tnet) VALUES
('NY', '2022-02-07', 4), ('CA', '2022-02-07', 5), ('WA', '2022-02-07', 6),
('NY', '2022-03-07', 4), ('CA', '2022-03-07', 5), ('WA', '2022-03-07', 6),
('NY', '2022-04-07', 1), ('CA', '2022-04-07', 2), ('WA', '2022-04-07', 3),
('NY', '2022-05-07', 1), ('CA', '2022-05-07', 2), ('WA', '2022-05-07', 3),
('NY', '2022-06-07', 1), ('CA', '2022-06-07', 2), ('WA', '2022-06-07', 3),
('NY', '2022-07-07', 1), ('CA', '2022-07-07', 2), ('WA', '2022-07-07', 3),
('NY', '2022-08-07', 1), ('CA', '2022-08-07', 2), ('WA', '2022-08-07', 3),
('NY', '2022-09-07', 1), ('CA', '2022-09-07', 2), ('WA', '2022-09-07', 3),
('NY', '2022-10-07', 1), ('CA', '2022-10-07', 2), ('WA', '2022-10-07', 3),
('NY', '2022-11-07', 1), ('CA', '2022-11-07', 2), ('WA', '2022-11-07', 3),
('NY', '2022-12-07', 1), ('CA', '2022-12-07', 2), ('WA', '2022-12-07', 3),
('NY', '2023-01-07', 1), ('CA', '2023-01-07', 2), ('WA', '2023-01-07', 3),
('NY', '2023-02-07', 1), ('CA', '2023-02-07', 2), ('WA', '2023-02-07', 3),
('NY', '2023-03-07', 1), ('CA', '2023-03-07', 2), ('WA', '2023-03-07', 3);
```

```
SELECT CASE SORTCODE WHEN 'AA' THEN 'Total' ELSE SORTCODE END AS STATE,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-02-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS JAN_TOTALREV,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-03-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS FEB_TOTALREV,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-04-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS MAR_TOTALREV,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-05-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS APR_TOTALREV,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-06-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS MAY_TOTALREV,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-07-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS JUN_TOTALREV,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-08-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS JUL_TOTALREV,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-09-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS AUG_TOTALREV,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-10-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS SEP_TOTALREV,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-11-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS OCT_TOTALREV,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-12-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS NOV_TOTALREV,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2023-01-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS DEC_TOTALREV
FROM [dbo].[Example]
GROUP BY SORTCODE
```

Instead of having to hard code "CASE WHEN LOADDATE='specific date'" I was wondering if there was a way I could automate this?

Comment: Have you considered `DATEADD`?

Comment: When I tried DATEADD I kept getting stuck with a error "Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Comment: Is `LOADDATE` *not* a date and time data type? That's your *real* problem.

Comment: There just isn't enough detail here for an answer. You need to provide sample data, desired output and table definitions.

Comment: Why the 7th and not the 5th (today's date)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good case for a pivot function.  You're pivoting by month, the only catch is you select your months a bit different and it looks like you wanted to filter from February of one year to February of the next in your output.  When you write a pivot any column you don't specify in the Pivot section is automatically used to group results.  The query below produces the same output as your last query:

```
DECLARE @startdate date = '2022-02-01'
DECLARE @enddate date = '2023-02-01'

SELECT PVT.SortCode AS [State]
      ,PVT.[2] AS [JAN_TOTALREV] 
      ,PVT.[3] AS [FEB_TOTALREV]
      ,PVT.[4] AS [MAR_TOTALREV]
      ,PVT.[5] AS [APR_TOTALREV]
      ,PVT.[6] AS [MAY_TOTALREV]
      ,PVT.[7] AS [JUN_TOTALREV]
      ,PVT.[8] AS [JUL_TOTALREV]
      ,PVT.[9] AS [AUG_TOTALREV]
      ,PVT.[10] AS [SEP_TOTALREV]
      ,PVT.[11] AS [OCT_TOTALREV]
      ,PVT.[12] AS [NOV_TOTALREV]
      ,PVT.[1] as [DEC_TOTALREV]
  FROM (

SELECT SortCode
      ,MONTH(LoadDate) [MonthNum]
      ,Tnet
  FROM @ExampleData
WHERE LoadDate >= @startdate
  AND LoadDate < @enddate

) AS dT
PIVOT ( SUM(Tnet) FOR MonthNum IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
--since SortCode is ommitted this gets identified as a grouping column automatically
) AS PVT
```

If you want more information on pivots you can refer to the Microsoft documentation at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16

edit: If you want to know how to automatically create the start and end date for the filter, you can use a SQL function like `DATEFROMPARTS()`.  An example you can play around with is:

```
DECLARE @currentyear smallint = YEAR(GETDATE());
DECLARE @startdate date = DATEFROMPARTS(@currentyear - 1, 2, 1);
DECLARE @enddate date = DATEFROMPARTS(@currentyear, 2, 1);
SELECT @startdate AS [startdate], @enddate AS [enddate];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off modifying your CASE's to not be so specific. You don't seem to care which year LoadDate is in, just which month (and possibly day?). If we changed them to just look at the month, we can simply add a WHERE clause to only bring back rows in the last 12 months:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SortCode = 'AA' THEN 'Total' ELSE SortCode END AS State,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,LoadDate) = 1  THEN Tnet END),0) AS JAN_TOTALREV,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,LoadDate) = 2  THEN Tnet END),0) AS FEB_TOTALREV,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,LoadDate) = 3  THEN Tnet END),0) AS MAR_TOTALREV,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,LoadDate) = 4  THEN Tnet END),0) AS APR_TOTALREV,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,LoadDate) = 5  THEN Tnet END),0) AS MAY_TOTALREV,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,LoadDate) = 6  THEN Tnet END),0) AS JUN_TOTALREV,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,LoadDate) = 7  THEN Tnet END),0) AS JUL_TOTALREV,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,LoadDate) = 8  THEN Tnet END),0) AS AUG_TOTALREV,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,LoadDate) = 9  THEN Tnet END),0) AS SEP_TOTALREV,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,LoadDate) = 10 THEN Tnet END),0) AS OCT_TOTALREV,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,LoadDate) = 11 THEN Tnet END),0) AS NOV_TOTALREV,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,LoadDate) = 12 THEN Tnet END),0) AS DEC_TOTALREV
  FROM @ExampleData
 WHERE LoadDate > DATEADD(MONTH,-12,GETDATE())
 GROUP BY CASE WHEN SortCode = 'AA' THEN 'Total' ELSE SortCode END
```